# Why different behaviour of both function in term of their respective scopes?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function test1(args){
   let age = 23;   // place debugger 1 here
   var name = 'prajval';
}
test2();

function test2(...args){
   let age = 23;   // place debugger 2 here
   var name = 'prajval';
}
test1();
```

---

scope at debugger 1:
**Local**
this: Window,
age: undefined,
args: undefined,
name: undefined

**Global**

---

---

scope at debugger 2:
**Block**
age: undefined,
name: undefined,

**Local**
this: Window,
args: []

**Global**

---

In test2() method when we used ...args as parameter that makes all other variable declarations of test2() method in block scope.

But I expected all of them (args and variable declaration) to be in the local scope itself just like test1().

Why this kind of different and unexpected behaviour is seen ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript makes a distinction between complex parameter declarations and simple (ES5-compatible) parameter declarations. The former are creating an extra scope where only the parameters but not the variables declared in the body are visible. It does not make a difference for the rest parameter syntax in your example, but it does when there are default initialisers since those might contain closures (or worse, `eval`):

```js
var x = 1;
(function(f = (() => x)) {
  var x = 2;
  console.log(f()); // Which variable "x" will f() return? Surprise!
})();
```

There's [a consideration to drop this distinction](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/623) and just always use two separate scopes - they would only be observable in the debugger anyway. However this might confuse people who expect that `function(x) { var x; }` has only a single `x` variable, and implementations would want to optimise away the unreachable binding anyway.